# How to integrate a Bézier function?

Tags: numerical-integration, splines

I have:

```
points = {{0, 100}, {250, 0}, {0, 300}, {500, 500}}
```

And I want to know the area below the curve, so I came to:

```
f = BezierFunction[points]

NIntegrate[f, {x, 0, 1}]
```

But it failed to execute:

```
NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand BezierFunction[{{0.,1.}},<>] has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0,1}}. >>
```

So how do I numerically integrate a Bézier curve correctly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since `f[t]` yields in effect `{x[t], y[t]}` and the area under a curve (with `y[t] > 0`) is given by the integral of `y[t] x'[t]` (i.e., $\int y\;dx$), then the following should work, assuming `x[t]` is increasing.

```
dA[f_, t_?NumericQ] := Last[f[t]] First[f'[t]];
NIntegrate[dA[f, t], {t, 0, 1}]
(*  150000.  *)
```

One can extend this to other forms, e.g. to closed curves, via Green's Theorem, with `dA[f_, x_?NumericQ] := f[x].Cross[f'[x]]/2`.

Answer (score 5):

You should note that `NIntegrate` normally consumes standard functions or `InterpolatingFunction`. A `BezierFunction` is a parametric function and will not work right away with the integrator.

You can do the following by the way.

```
mesh = DiscretizeGraphics[ParametricPlot[f[t], {t, 0, 1}]];
nf = Interpolation[MeshCoordinates[mesh]];
NIntegrate[nf[x], Evaluate@Flatten@{x, nf["Domain"]}]
```

> `150000.`

I basically took the point-wise representation of your `BezierFunction` from a parametric plot using the `DiscretizeGraphics` functionality of MMA. You can see the sampled points along with your curve.

[image]

```
Show[Graphics[{Red, PointSize[Large], Point[points], Orange, Dashed, 
   Line[points]}, Axes -> True], 
 ParametricPlot[f[t], {t, 0, 1}, 
  PlotStyle -> {{LightBlue, Thickness@.01}}], mesh, Frame -> True]
```

P.S: Note that the above process will not work on arbitrary `BezierFunction` as 2D Bézier curves are by definition allowed to resolve into an one to many mapping which can't be integrated.

Answer (score 4):

The nice thing about *Mathematica* is that it often allows you to do a thing in more than one fashion. For this answer, I will evaluate the *exact* integral, using a slight tweak of Michael's strategy.

The wrinkle here is that we fall back on the definition of the Bézier curve as an appropriate linear combination of Bernstein functions. This allows you to have the $x$ and $y$ components of the curve kept separately.

Thus,

```
pts = {{0, 100}, {250, 0}, {0, 300}, {500, 500}};
n = Length[pts] - 1;
{f[t_], g[t_]} = BernsteinBasis[n, Range[0, n], t].pts;
Integrate[g[t] f'[t], {t, 0, 1}]
   150000
```